# cache image using unique id (not based on URL) in react native

Tags: amazon-s3, image-caching, react-native-fast-image

i have a one project. in that their is a list which i get from api and the api's response contains a one image url which frequently changes ,but in that one one part of image name is common and the image also a same. but the later half signature is changes whenever is called it.So how can i cache
this image in react native using any if the caching library or should i need to cache it manually ?

ex:- https://abcImage.png/..../.... (where .... contains any unique signature text)

Thanks in advance